# Explanation of Wikipedia's definition of a function problem

Tags: turing-machines

On the Wikipedia article for function problem it currently defines a function problem as follows:

> A functional problem $P$ is defined as a relation $R$ over strings of an arbitrary alphabet $\Sigma$: $R\subseteq\Sigma^*\times\Sigma^*$. An algorithm that solves $P$ if for every input $x$ such that there exists a $y$ satisfying $(x,y)\in R$, the algorithm produces one such $y$.

My question is this: why *one such* $y$ - doesn't a function have unique output?

My guess: Does this have to do with the fact that Turing Machines (one possible instance of a model for computation) will sometimes output strings which differ only by trailing zeros or something, but you want to ignore that in these problems?

Comment: relations don't have a unique pairing of $y$ for each $x$. In other words, if $R$ was a function, it would have to return the output of the function for every input

Comment: @DonThousand then why is it called a function problem?

Comment: Because the result is a function. The Turing machine outputs one $y$ given input $x.$ So you are taking a relation $R$ and producing a function which is a subset of $R.$ (or really a partial function, which is commonly simply called a function in computability discussions - if there is no $y.$)

Comment: Think of $R$ as a *specification* of a function. The specification may be loose, i.e, it might allow several different "implementations". E.g., If  $xRy$  means $x < y$ for $x, y \in \Bbb{N}$, the solution could be $x \mapsto x + 1$ or $x \mapsto x + 2$ or ...

Comment: Perhaps as opposed to "all such $y$," or "at least one such $y$."